# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I cannot call `.bind(this)` on any of the functions that I am using to set the state of my variables. When I try and change the way I call my `.bind` it will run properly but nothing on the page will change or be affected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Farmer.css';

export class FarmerProfile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isHome: true, isReservations: false, isUpdateFarm: false, isCurrentCrops: false};
    }

    showHomeBox(){
        this.setState = { isHome: true, isReservations: false, isUpdateFarm: false, isCurrentCrops: false};
    }

    showReservationsBox (){
        this.setState = { isHome: false, isReservations: true, isUpdateFarm: false, isCurrentCrops: false};
        console.log("tried");
    }

    showUpdateFarmBox(){
        this.setState = { isHome: false, isReservations: false, isUpdateFarm: true, isCurrentCrops: false};
    }

    showCurrentCropsBox(){
        this.setState = { isHome: false, isReservations: false, isUpdateFarm: false, isCurrentCrops: true};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
                <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
                
                <title>Farmer Profile Page</title>
            </head>
                <body>
                
                    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css"></link>
                    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick= {this.showReservationsBox.bind(this)}>Primary</button>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row profile">
                            <div class="col-md-3 border">
                                <div class="profile-sidebar">
                                    <div class="profile-userpic">
                                        <img src="https://k48b9e9840-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/COVID-19-Relief_Small-Farms--1024x614.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></img>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-usertitle">
                                        <div class="profile-usertitle-farmname">
                                            Farm Name
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="profile-usertitle-farmemail">
                                            farmEmail@gmail.com
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-userbuttons">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Follow</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Message</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-usermenu">
                                        <ul class="nav">
                                            <li class="active">
                                                <a href="#home" onClick={this.showHomeBox.bind(this)}>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                                                Home </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#reservations" onClick={this.showReservationsBox.bind(this)}>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                                Reservations </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#update" onClick={this.showUpdateFarmBox().bind(this), console.log("CLICK")}>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                                Update Farm </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#crops" onClick={this.showCurrentCropsBox.bind(this)}>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></i>
                                                Current Crops </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="active-selection-content">
                                {this.state.isHome && <HomeBox />}
                                {this.state.isReservations && <ReservationsBox />}
                                {this.state.isCurrentCrops && <CurrentCropsBox />}
                                {this.state.isUpdateFarm && <UpdateFarmBox />}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
    </html>
        )
    }
}

class HomeBox extends React.Component  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Home Box</div>
        );
    }
}

class ReservationsBox extends React.Component  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Reservations Box</div>
        );
    }
}

class UpdateFarmBox extends React.Component  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Update Farm Box</div>
        );
    }
}

class CurrentCropsBox extends React.Component  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Current Crops Box</div>
        );
    }
}

export default FarmerProfile
```

I have tried changing the way I define the functions, the way I have called the functions, the way I check to see which page should be called. I can't figure out why it will not let me bind this to the state

Comment: `this.setState` is a function. change it to `this.setState({})`

Answer (score 4):

You are setting state in a wrong way. `setState` is a method, not a property, which means that you have to call it as a method and pass arguments to it.

So instead of:

```
this.setState = { isHome: false, isReservations: true, isUpdateFarm: false, isCurrentCrops: false };
```

Try rather:

```
this.setState({
  isHome: false,
  isReservations: true,
  isUpdateFarm: false,
  isCurrentCrops: false
});
```

Comment: Dang, thought I had already tried that but guess not. That fixed it, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Change your current code like below.

Currently: (Incorrect)

```
this.setState = {key: value}
```

Correct:

```
this.setState({key: value})
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I am not able to find `.bind()` where you are facing the issue,

But maybe one possible solution could be using arrow functions `() => {}`

Arrow function always keep `this` to class level, instead of DOM level at some use cases(react-handlers). Maybe if you can comment the specific line where you are facing the issues, I can help better!

Also,
I found out that you're using `this.setState = { newState }`
`this.setState` is a function, you pass your updated state to `this.setState` as a parameter,

```js
this.setState({ newState })
```